# Re-ordering A-Frame entitles defined in JavaScript, to work around transparency issues

Tags: aframe, webvr

I need some A-Frame entities to be partially transparent, and overlap. This only works if the farthest entity is defined first (as seen at https://glitch.com/edit/#!/trail-cause)

I'm using the pool component to manage my entities:

`<a-scene ... pool__clouds="mixin:cloud; size:10; dynamic:true">`

As the user flies along, I pull objects from the pool:

`let cloudEl = sceneEl.components.pool__clouds.requestEntity();`

These are placed *farther* from the user than previous entities. Unfortunately, that's exactly backward for transparency.

Is there a way to pull objects from the pool in reverse order?

Or must I define the entities in HTML and manage them without the pool component?

Comment: Have you tried something like `.insertBefore()` to rearrange the element's HTML position when you request it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Answer (score 0):

Your issue should be solved by using the material property `alphaTest:0.5`. it should properly hadle transparency.

I can even back it up with a [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/flawless-ladybug?path=index.html:15:102). :)

---

I'm not good at shaders, as far as i know `alpha-test` takes care for proper RGBA rendering in openGL, or webGL.

---

Rearranging is a workaround, but no need for workarounds here.

Comment: Thanks, that does solve the issue of hard, rectangular edges. Unfortunately, that's at the expense of them looking like clouds! Smaller values, such as `alphaTest:0.001' change them from hard-edged rectangles to hard-edged clouds, which is not as bad, but still not the effect I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure, are You trying to make a 3d smoke with .pngs ? because `alphaTest:0.5` makes the alpha channel work like it should, fixing 'transparency issues'. Check out the cloud You're using: https://imgur.com/a/Zj8Rc. `alphaTest:0.5` makes it look exactly like the png. If You want some other cloud, you should consider making Your own cloud pngs. Just open it with gimp, or photoshop and brush some white with opacity 0.5. Oh, and the white sky also doesn't help :)